# Delete partial data in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, database

I have a mongoDB collection which has a count of `372985` names, I want to delete entries after `200000` so that total number of entries after deletion reduces from `372985` to `200000`

How can I do this by mongoDB query?

**Usecase**

My python code is unable to process huge data as per my machine configuration, So I want to reduce the size of mongo collection so that it can run in limited RAM.

If this cannot be done by mongo query, Can someone give hint for trying python to do the same.

Comment: Can we make use of skip and delete the records in a document cursor loop

Comment: @PraneethGudumasu: Can you illustrate by an example?

Comment: try{
     
        MongoClient client = new MongoClient( "localhost" , 27017);
        
        MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("students");
        
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("grades");
      
       MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().skip(10).iterator();
       
   
       

    while(cursor.hasNext()){
     
      
      Document doc = cursor.next();
      
 
       collection.deleteOne(doc);

      
     }

Comment: is this a mongoshell query or what?
I mean where  to run this?

Comment: That one is for java driver. I Reckon, we can execute cursors from mongo shell as well

Comment: Why are you loading the data in memory? You really shouldn't delete your documents because of that. Please add your script to to question.

Comment: Yaa I know that's very unefficient, But somehow I can manage my huge scripts which will take some time. But right now I need to get to results with whatever amount of data my computer allows

Comment: @PraneethGudumasu: Let me try in mongo shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in steps, cause MongoDB needs a query to match documents to be deleted; MongoDB cannot use `skip` or `limit` when removing documents.

1. find (the ids of) documents that you want to delete, using skip to jump to documents after 200000
2. delete the documents that belong to the list found in 1

You can try in mongo shell:

```
var to_delete = db.collection.find({}, {_id : 1})
        .skip(200000)
        .toArray()
        .map(function(doc) { return doc._id; });

db.collection.remove({_id: {$in: to_delete}})
```